# var keyword in c# wrongly deduces type as dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, var

My understanding of the `var`-keyword in c# is that it is basically the equivalent of `auto` in c++ - deducing the correct type of a variable at compile-time based on what is being assigned to it (i.e. using the type of a constant being assigned or the return-type of a function).

However, I have come across a case where even if I assign the return value of a function to a variable that I declare via the `var`-keyword, the compiler will (wrongly) deduce the variable's type to be `dynamic` as long as the *input* to the function was `dynamic`.

---

Let's consider some examples:

```cs
public static string F(object data)
{
    return data.GetType().ToString();
}
//[...]

var x = (dynamic)42;
var y = F(x);
```

Here, I would expect the type of `y` to be deduced as `string` since that is the return-type of `F`.

Instead, both hovering over the variable in my IDE as well as looking at its type in the debugger show `y` as being `dynamic`:
[image: y being displayed as dynamic{string} instead of plain string]

---

Now, this could be simply chalked up to the IDE being weird but surely this doesn't affect anything at runtime?
Well, consider this other example:

```cs
public static dynamic Get(bool b)
{
    if (b) return new SomeClass() { Name = "some name" };
    else return new SomeOtherClass() { Value = 42 };
}

public static Memory<byte> G(object data)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(data.GetType());
    using MemoryStream ms = new();
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, data);
    return new Memory<byte>(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
}
//[...]
var input = Get(true);
var data = G(input);
var span = data.Span;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(span));
```

Here, I would expect `data` to be a `Memory<byte>` (because that is the return-type that is defined for `G`) so that I can access its `.Span`-property.
Instead, accessing `data.Span` throws a `System.InvalidProgramException` with 'Cannot create boxed ByRef-like values.'

If I replace `var data = G(input);` with `Memory<byte> data = G(input);` everything works as intended:
I can get the `Span` and do further operations on it without issue.

---

My questions now are the:
What is my misunderstanding about the details behind `var` / how does it differ from `auto`?
How exactly *does* it deduce the type of a variable?
Under what circumstances will `var` become `dynamic` and how do I avoid those (other than not using `var` and always specifying the type explicitly).

In case this makes a difference:
I have tested this using Visual Studio 2022 (v17.4.0) targeting .net 6.0

Comment: Right, forgot to add that: This is Visual Studio 2022 and .net 6.0

Comment: I tried this out, for me F() returns a string into the var. Is there any chance of F() being a different function that returns `dynamic` hidden somewhere?

Comment: This is a new project I created specifically to produce a minimal reproducible example, although renaming the function to something like `DefinitelyNoCollisoinsHere` also does not change anything.

Comment: Plus, keep in mind that `.GetType()` always works correctly, so this may just be our IDEs displaying `y` differently. Which is why the second example is more important, as it actually produces decidedly different behaviour at runtime.

Comment: FWIW, I can replicate what you're seeing. When I use the code above in a fresh project and pause on a breakpoint, in the Locals pane under Type I see `dynamic (string)` for `y`. If I change the `x` line to `var x = 42;`, then I see `string` for `y` instead.

Comment: To make sure, this is the full code I am using: https://gist.github.com/Entropy0/92b11e92dfa57de7ec01143bfbd045a7

Comment: I don't think it's just the IDE display being odd. Since `dynamic` supports any operation, in theory we should be able to write and compile `x.ThisMethodDoesNotExist()` and `y.ThisMethodDoesNotExist()` and not get a compile-time error. And indeed, I can do that in my project and I don't get a compile-time error. (Those would fail at runtime, of course.) In contrast, if I change the statement for `y` to `var y = (string)F(x);`, `y.ThisMethodDoesNotExist()` no longer compiles. So the variable's type really is `dynamic`. That seems...wrong...given `F`'s declared return type.

Comment: Maybe you should create an issue on the [microsoft github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues). I'm interested to know what they find.

Comment: I believe this is due to *dynamic binding*, per [11.3.1 in the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1131-general). It seems (a guess), the compiler/IDE/runtime stops trying to infer type information when *dynamic binding* is encountered. `dynamic` can usually be replaced with `object` (§8.7), so one fix is `var data = G((object)input);` This fixes the type to `Memory<byte>` instead of the `dynamic?` without the `object` cast (and fixes the runtime exception).

Comment: "When no dynamic expressions are involved, C# defaults to static binding, which means that the compile-time types of subexpressions are used in the selection process. However, when one of the subexpressions in the operations listed above is a dynamic expression, the operation is instead dynamically bound." from the above 11.3.1

Comment: @BurnsBA - I think that's the answer. The `x` in `F(x)` is the dynamic expression that taints (as it were) the result. Nice one!!